# how to process excel file using apache nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to work with excel using nifi.

Can anyone please guide me on this would be great.

I have tried looking for it but no luck

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What version of NiFi are you using? As of version 1.2.0 (thanks to [NIFI-2613](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2613)), you should be able to use [ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-poi-nar/1.2.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.poi.ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor/index.html), then continue the flow by manipulating the file as CSV.

Comment: Thank you so much. Really appreciate